# Js? Jquery? Can this be done...switch to dropdown for change and then back again on the fly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a table which contains user choices of a certain type... with each choice they can then categorise them in order of preference e.g. choice 1, choice 2, choice 3 etc. their first, second, third choices of all time

So, I have a list of all their choices which might be for example:

film name 1 :: choice 1

film name 2 :: choice 1

film name 3 :: choice 2

film name 4 :: choice 3

film name 5 :: choice 3

etc etc

What I want them to be able to do is click on their choice preference, e.g. their preference for film name 2, and it then change to a dropdown box to allow them to change it from choice 1 to choice 2, then when click choice 2 on the dropdown it updates the table and goes back to simple data listing. Obviously I want this functionality for every row displayed.

Is this possible? If so how? Are there any code/functions/classes written already for such functionality?

I use PHP with MySQL db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done, assuming you don't care if it makes it difficult for users who can't or don't use a mouse. It's not difficult with jQuery, though it shouldn't be too much harder without. One approach would be to start with a hidden drop-down in all the appropriate places and then just show and hide them based on user actions. The other approach would be to append a drop-down when needed and remove it when finished.

Following is a dodgy (but working: http://jsbin.com/ocogop/2/edit#javascript,html,live) implementation that I whipped up just as a proof of concept.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var choices = "<select class='choices'>"
                   +"<option value='Choice 1'>Choice 1</option>"
                   +"<option value='Choice 2'>Choice 2</option>"
                   +"<option value='Choice 3'>Choice 3</option>"
                   +"<option value='Choice 4'>Choice 4</option>"
                   +"</select>";

  $(".update").click(function() {
     var $this = $(this),
         currentChoice;
     // don't continue if there's already a select in this cell
     if ($this.find("select").length != 0)
        return;
     currentChoice = $this.html();
     var $choices = $(choices);
     $this.empty().append($choices);
     $choices.val(currentChoice);
  });

  $(document).on("change", ".choices", function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.parent().html($this.val());
     return false;
  });
});
</script>

<table id="list">
   <tr>
      <td>Film Name 1</td>
      <td class="update">Choice 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>File Name 2</td>
      <td class="update">Choice 3</td>
   </tr>
   <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

This should get you started, though there are many ways it could be improved (I may well get comments telling me all the things I did "wrong", but really I don't have time right now to tidy it up). Note that the above uses `.on()` but for versions of jQuery older than 1.7 you should use `.delegate()`.

Comment: 4 things, firstly, awesome, thank you - secondly, when the dropdown appears it appears on Choice 1, if that is then clicked nothing happens, as if that choice is not valid? thirdly, is it possible to make it go back to normal if the user clicks away from the dropdown (e.g. they clicked it but didnt mean to)? lastly, how would this integrate with changing the MySql db for that particular entry - many thanks again, it is appreciated

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd already coded it to have the dropdown appear with the existing choice already selected, but I didn't quite have it right. I've updated my answer (and the jsbin demo) with a quick hack to make it work. As far as hiding when you click away, I'd suggest you set focus to the dropdown when showing it then give it a blur handler to hide it again. As far as updating your database, if you want an instant update put an ajax call in the event handler that hides the dropdown.

Comment: I am still struggling with how to add onblur i'm afraid, if a user clicks away from the select. Also, can I then use withing the select options,onchange="this.form.submit();" to submit the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this with a basic jquery form styling plugin:

http://uniformjs.com/

Thats a basic one. You would just style the select elements to appear as though they are not dropdowns by removing the borders or something.

Most of these kinds of plugins have many options and simulating your desired effect should be pretty easy to achieve.

Comment: This does not allow you to remove styling all togther i don't believe, i.e. making it look like a normal text entry then when clicked change to dropdown for user to change the entry

Comment: this one example may not, but the general idea is that many jquery form stylers allow you to template your forms so you can add custom images and such for arrows, etc. So it's clever use of the tools provided and not so much a direct application to this problem. Additionally, focus listeners can update css.